# Control panel disabled on liferay portal

Tags: debian, tomcat7, liferay

I have just finished installing a new liferay portal into a Tomcat server.
I am trying to configure the portal but everything under "control panel"seems to be disabled.

Particularly, I was trying to reach: control panel > settings > authentication
When I click on authentication, it won't do anything. Even the fields that were already loaded won't work - disabled.

Does any one know if this is a setting issue (everything out of that area works)?

I had a lot of permission problems with liferay+debian, I though this could be an extra one. I also think this could be a liferay setting I don't know about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a extremely odd behavior. It took me a day to investigate. No errors on Catalina.out or messages on the browser. In the end, I removed everything from webapps, and copied from a freshly downloaded bundle (tomcat+liferay). I was using the liferay.war before.

I really don't know what went wrong, but coping from the bundle into my own tomcat installation solved the problem - and the process was simpler than following liferay's process to install in previously existing tomcat (not bundled).